# How to use Cuda data structures in .cpp files

Tags: c++, data-structures, cuda

Is it possible to use the Cuda-defined data structures, such as float3, float4, dim3 etc. in a .cpp file?

How would you go about achieving this if it is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind expanding on that?

Comment: There's nothing magic about most of the CUDA data structures, so you should be able to just pull in the headers, or copy the class definitions over. Then define some variables and use them. The question is why you'd want to. It's not that there's anything particularly special about float4 or dim3.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can.  Just `#include "vector_types.h"` (make sure the CUDA include directory is in your `-I` path).  I think [this code sample](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-cc-sdk-code-samples#cppIntegration) demonstrates it (not that you really need an example for something this simple).

Also, some of the CUDA SDK code samples include a header called "vector_math.h", which defines a number of operators (+, *, dot, etc.) for the vector types.  That would be in the SDK common/include directory, I believe (note that this is not a standard, supported part of CUDA -- it's an example of code you could write yourself).