# Using float4 inside a C file

Tags: c, cuda

Is it possible to use CUDA "float4" data type in a C code by including the "cuda.h" library?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266857/how-to-use-cuda-data-structures-in-cpp-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just `#include "vector_types.h"`

https://code.google.com/p/hydrazine/source/browse/trunk/hydrazine/cuda/include/vector_types.h?r=23

Answer (score 3):

If you're only after the `float4` data type, define it yourself:

```
typedef struct float4 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float w;
} float4;
```

Comment: This is not exactly CUDA's `float4` since it's not aligned!